# Laravel 9.x After submitting the form Mailgun returns not defined Error. [Email couldn't delivered]

Tags: php, laravel, email

Trying to send data with input form. User sends information such as name, email, subject and the message. This form is getting used for reporting issues to do admin. When submit the form, returns Mailgun not defined error.

new to laravel and mvc.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3GE.png)

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=Mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@MyUsername.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

**config/mail.php**

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
        ],
        
    ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'failover' => 
        [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
```

**app/Mail/contacter.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class contacter extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $emailData;
  
    public function __construct($emailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $emailData;
      
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Message')
                    ->view('mail');
    }
}
```

**ContactUsFormController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\Contact;
use app\Mail\contacter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


class ContactUsFormController extends Controller
{
    public function createForm(Request $req){
        return view('contact');
    }
    public function ContactUsForm(Request $req){
                //form validation 
                $this->validate($req,[
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required | email',
                    'subject' => 'required',
                    'message' => 'required'
                ]);
                $email = [
                    'name' => $req->get('name'),
                    'email' => $req->get('email'),
                    'subject' => $req->get('subject'),
                    'message' => $req->get('message')
                ];

              Mail::to(env('ADMIN'))->send(new contacter($email));

            return back()->with('success', 'We have recieved your message and will reply to ' . $email['email'] . ' email address!');


   }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/contact', [ContactUsFormController::class, 'createForm']);
Route::post('/contact', [ContactUsFormController::class, 'ContactUsForm'])->name('contact.store');
```

**mail.blade**

```
    <h1>About : {{ $emailData['subject'] }}</h1>
    <p>From : {{ $emailData['name'] }}</p>
    <p>Reply To : {{$emailData['email']}}</p> <br /><br /><br />
    <p>{{$emailData['message']}}</p>
     
    <br />
    <p>END</p>
```

Comment: its a typo, `MAIL_MAILER=Mailgun` should be `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun`

Comment: No it's not I tried `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` but still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

from your `.env` it looks like you using your mailgun smtp credentials

then you should define your driver as SMTP

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: When I do that I'm having this error `Class "app\Mail\contacter" not found` is there something wrong with my `contacter.php` file? or the controller?

Comment: try replace `new contacter($email)` with `new app\Mail\contacter($email)`

Comment: No having this error -> https://ibb.co/71zKpww

Comment: sorry I missed this try again with `new App\Mail\contacter($email)`

Answer (score 0):

change in contracter.php file

```
//public $emailData;
// to

public $mailData;

public function __construct($emailData)
{
    $this->mailData = $emailData;
}
```

Comment: No still having the same error. `Mailer [Mailgun] is not defined.` Changing .env file `MAIL_MAILER=smtp` and `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use mailgun smtp, set your .env to :
MAIL_MAILER=smtp

If you want to use mailgun api, set your .env to :
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun

Then update your config/services.php inside 'mailgun' array :

```
'domain' => 'MAILGUN_DOMAIN',  

 'secret' => 'MAILGUN_SECRET',  ==>> your private api key

 'endpoint' => 'api.mailgun.net',
```